# Phone Number Matching with some Boundry Condition

Tags: regex

10 digit number starting with 6,7,8,9 or an 11 digit number starting with 0 or +91. The number has to be checked if it is present as a separate word (demarcated by spaces on both sides or space on side and a period/comma/newline on the other or a period/comma on both sides, or a period/comma on one side and newline on the other) and not part of any running text.

```
(?:[,\s]|^)(\+91[6-9]\d{9}|[6-9]\d{9}|0[6-9]\d{9})
```

```
valid number 
with comma 
8126131525,8126131526,08126131527,+918126131528 

with space 
8126131525 8126131526 08126131527 +918126131528
```

Examples it should match:

```
8126131525,8126131526,08126131527,+918126131528 8126131525 8126131526 08126131527 +918126131528
```

Examples not to match :

```
amit.81261215255
.81261315253
+9181261315258989
0812613152584
,+9181261315258989
81261215257.amit
amit@81261215255
06126131525@amit
```

I am new to regex

Comment: re: *'checked if it is present as a separate word (demarcated by spaces on both sides or space on side and a period/comma/newline on the other or a period/comma on both sides, or a period/comma on one side and newline on the other'* can you give some examples please

Comment: valid number 
with comma 
8126131525,8126131526,08126131527,+918126131528
without comma
8126131525 8126131526 08126131527 +918126131528

Comment: `918126131528` has 12 digits. Maybe e.g. [`^(?:(?:\+91\d|0\d|[6-9])\d{9}\b[., ]?)+\b$`](https://regex101.com/r/B4BXjM/1) - Please provide better description and examples of input/desired output, also mention your environment.

Comment: @bobblebubble
(?:[,\s]|^)(\+91[6-9]\d{9}|[6-9]\d{9}|0[6-9]\d{9})
this is my regex the problem is comming when i get 
+91812613152577 (invalid number because its length is more than 13 and still i am getting match upto 13 . I want to number to be string in that parameter length only .

Comment: @Amitsingh0823 I see you got it solved already by adding a `\b` *word boundary* after. If you want to shorten it a bit: [`(?:[,\s]|^)(?:\+91|0)?[6-9]\d{9}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/zIdxnp/1)

Comment: ya this \b worked fine . thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<!\w)(0\d|\+91|[6-9])\d{9}(?!\w)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/McGoFEeeZX3mT6).

The look arounds at each end are "not a word char", which matches end of input too.

This uses an alternation for +91 *or* a character in the range 6-9.

Comment: not working fine a.8126131525 also matching .

Comment: @Amitsingh0823 please explain in detail why `8126131525` should not match.

Comment: Can you fix it for starting with zero also .

Comment: @Amitsingh0823 OK - fixed for zero. I still don't understand why "a.8126131525" should not match.

Comment: It was matching . But early i didnt want dot and number .but later i changed .

Comment: Thanks for adding examples that should not match, but none of them match except `
06126131525@amit`. Is `@` also not valid separator? Did you mean to include a 10-digit number with a dot as separator to that list? Please edit your question to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This work fine for me

```
`(?:[,\s\.]|^)(\+91[6-9]\d{9}|[6-9]\d{9}|0[6-9]\d{9})\b`g
```